# Image and data matrices

Tags: image, matlab, matrix

When I read some image in `MATLAB`, do we say that this image is also a *data matrix*, or are they are two different things? If they are different, how can we convert an image to a data matrix in `MATLAB`?

As far as I know, an image is a matrix of pixels, isn't it?

Comment: MATLAB = matrix laboratory. Anything is a kind of matrix, which is simply multidimensional array of scalars, object, char, etc. Image is not an exception. It's a 3-dimensional array of uint8 data type.

Answer (score 1):

When you load an image, it is automaticlly represented as a matrix.

```
>> A = imread('example.jpeg');
>> size(A)
ans = 512   512     3
```

So A is a 512-512-3 array- which is  representing an RGB image!

TO understand the RGB-representation, try the following snipped, it should give you insight:

```
I = imread('example.jpeg');

%Red
R = I(:,:,1);
image(R), colormap([[0:1/255:1]', zeros(256,1), zeros(256,1)]), colorbar;
%Blue
B = I(:,:,3);
figure;
image(B), colormap([zeros(256,1), zeros(256,1), [0:1/255:1]']), colorbar;
%Green
G = I(:,:,2);
figure;
image(G), colormap([zeros(256,1),[0:1/255:1]', zeros(256,1)]), colorbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a data matrix. Most time it is `uint8` format when you load the image, sometimes in three dimension (RGB, HSV...), and sometimes in two (grayscale). To get more operations between the matrix, the best way is to convert the data to double format (just use `double`).

code example:

```
I=imread('img1.jpg');
I=double(I);
J=imread('img2.jpg');
J=double(J);
```

% you can implement various array operations such as multiplication, dot product, power, ..to name only a few

```
K = I.*J;
K1 = I.*(J<240);
K2 = J.^(0.5);
```

Comment: @AshleyMedway Thank you for your suggestion! Sample code added.

Answer (score 0):

Images are seen as data matrices, yes. There is one thing you should be aware of is that MATLAB treats **coordinates of matrices and images differently**.

See:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html

Confusing at first, but you get used to it. Use preferably the function of the Image Processing Toolbox, if you have it.

Exemple:

Let's create an upper triangular matrix of size (100x100) and display it as a binary image:

```
D=triu(ones(100,100));
imshow(D)
```

[image: Upper triangular matrix displayed]

Up to here, all is well, if I try to access element of this matrix with the usual indexing:

```
D(5, 10);
```

I get the value one, with is as expected as the index of the row (the firs one) is smaller than the one of the column.

Now if I use the interactive tool to get coordinates of points on the image clicked with the mouse like this (I selected the left one first):

```
imshow(D);
[x y]=getpts;
```

[image: Selected points]

It returns the following coordinates: (7,16) and (93,17).

Images are treated as having the x-axis from left to right and the y-axis from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

There are (at least) four kinds of images in Matlab:

1. *Grayscale images*: in this case yes, the image is just a matrix. Each matrix entry represents the gray level of the corresponding pixel.
2. *Indexed color images*: the image is described by a matrix and a colormap. Each row of the colormap is a three-element vector defining a color (in terms of three primary colors such as R, G, B). Each matrix entry contains a number which is a pointer to the colormap. Specifically it contains a row number of the colormap, such that the color of that pixel is described by the corresponding row of the colormap.
3. *Indexed color images with transparency information*: the image is described as in case 2 but in addition there is a transparency (alpha) matrix, which needs to be taken into account to render the actual color.
4. *Non-indexed color images*: the image is represented as a 3D array of size MxNx3, where MxN is the image size. The first two indices specify a pixel, and the third refers to each of the primary colors, usually  R, G, B. For example, the entry (m,n,1) indicates how much red the (m,n) pixel contains.

Depending on which image file format you have and how you read it into Matlab, you may get one of this four types. Also, you may get `double` or `uint8` values in the matrix/3D-array. See [`imread` documentation](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) for details.