# How can I display an image in the right order in a graph?

Tags: image, matlab, plot

I have a problem when I display an image in a plot.The image is upside down in the figure window. Do you know how to fix this problem?

Here is my code to display the image in the graph:

```
% Load the image
img = imread('KAM-Map_12s.bmp');
hold on;
% Plot the image, with x and y coordinnates
image([100 350],[3.5 4.7],img)
```

I already use the `function set(gca,'YDir','reverse')` to reverse the picture, however the graph is also reversed. I would appreciate any help from your part.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that the coordinates for images and matrices are different in MATLAB, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20887324/2777181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
image([100 350],[4.7 3.5],img)
```

since the rows of an image/matrix are stored from top to bottom, not from bottom to top.